# how to libsodium 1.0.18 install in shared server

Tags: server, libsodium

i want to install '**libsodium-1.0.18**' in my shared server like below way ..

```
curl -O https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/libsodium-1.0.18.tar.gz \
        && tar xfvz libsodium-1.0.18.tar.gz \
        && cd libsodium-1.0.18 \
        && ./configure \
        && make && make install \
        && pecl install -f libsodium
```

after installing below type error showing in last

[image]

Comment: `read-only file system` means that files cannot be written to at least one of the mounted partitions, the one that holds `/usr/local`.